# Is List<>.Sort() the best way to reduce the number of checks?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I am making a meme ranking app that would rank your favorite memes best to worst and remove the least ranked memes up to a point to remove extra bloat from old and outdated memes saving space on your disk. I thought that because the `List<T>.Sort()` function was pretty fast, it'll quickly help the user sort through possibly hundreds of memes. This was not the case because when I would try to use the sort using the method below I got some strange results.

```
// Using Task.Run() temp. due to the easy access. Will thread this properly in the future. 
Task.Run(() =>
{
    Manager.Files.Sort(delegate (Photo x, Photo y) {
        // I have Invoke built into the ChangeImage method but having double duty doesn't slow it down.
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            ChangeImage(pictureBox1, x.Filename);
            ChangeImage(pictureBox2, y.Filename);
        }));
        WaitForButtonPress.WaitOne(); // Pauses the thread until an image is chosen. 
        switch (LastButton)
        {
            case 1: // if x is better than y
                return 1;
            case 2: // if y is better than x
                return -1;
            case 3: // if y and x are equals
                return 0;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return 0; 
    });
});
```

The issue I'm having with this code is the fact that sometimes `pepe.jpg` and `isThisAPidgon.png` are often compared to each other multiple times especially after the end of a streak of showing up in the comparison. `pepe.jpg` vs. `1.jpg`, `pepe.jpg` vs. `2.png`... `pepe.jpeg` vs. `nth.jpg`, `pepe.jpg` vs. `isThisAPidgon.png`, then `isThisAPidgon.png` vs. `pepe.jpg` again but reversed. Upon finding this strange behavior I tried checking how many times they are called.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Number> numbers = new List<Number>();
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        numbers.Add(new Number() { Num = rand.Next(0, 500) });
    }

    foreach(Number num in numbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(num.num);
    }

    numbers.Sort((Number x, Number y) =>
    {
        int numx = x.Num;
        int numy = y.Num;
        if (numx > numy)
            return 1;
        else if (numy > numx)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;

        //return x.Num - y.Num;
    });

    int total = 0;
    foreach(Number num in numbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Num: {num.num} Times Checked: {num.timesChecked}");
        total += num.timesChecked;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Finished with {total} checks.");
}
```

Class Number:

```
class Number
{
    public Number()
    {

    }

    public int num;

    public int timesChecked = 0;

    public int Num { get { timesChecked++; return num; } set => num = value; }
}
```

With the `< == >` comparison returning 1, -1, or 0 and returning the difference of `x.num` and `y.num` both yield the same result: some appear way more often than some. Here are some examples.

```
#checked with differences
Num: 168 Times Checked: 8
Num: 170 Times Checked: 17
Num: 170 Times Checked: 316 #316?
Num: 170 Times Checked: 14
Num: 171 Times Checked: 15

#checked with differences
Num: 237 Times Checked: 12
Num: 237 Times Checked: 9
Num: 240 Times Checked: 105 #More reasonable... 
Num: 241 Times Checked: 14
Num: 242 Times Checked: 15

#checked with differences
Num: 395 Times Checked: 10
Num: 397 Times Checked: 8
Num: 398 Times Checked: 502 #How could it fail to sort this number in more tries than the array is long?
Num: 398 Times Checked: 7
Num: 399 Times Checked: 8

#checked with <==>
Num: 306 Times Checked: 15
Num: 306 Times Checked: 17
Num: 307 Times Checked: 756 #This is ridiculous how does this happen?
Num: 307 Times Checked: 13
Num: 309 Times Checked: 15
```

It seems that differences get below 10000 total checks but when checked with the <==>/1,-1,0 method it seems to consistently get above 15000 total. Is there a sorting algorithm that focuses on reducing the number of times an object needs to be compared to be sorted?

Edit: I made a mistake in the <==> comparison example. I'm using `x.Num` and `y.Num` twice which inflated the result. To fix this I stored the two properties as locals and it dropped the total number from above 15000 to below 10000 around 9000 while subtracting sill remains below 10000 around 8000.

Comment: Are your comparisons transitive? Meaning that if `A<B` then additionally, `B>A` must be true? And if `A<=B` and `B<=C` then it gives that `A<=C` must also be true?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes that is true. it wouldn't matter what order in memory each would appear in as long as the truth of `A<B` isn't changed so that would definitely mean `A<=B`, `B<=C` therefore `A<=C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most sort algorithms have a complexity O(n log n) and that means they need to perform that many comparisons in order to sort the data. So, no, you aren't going to be able to use Sort for what you are doing.

Secondly, some build in Sort methods switch behavior depending on the size of the list so your user interface may feel very different depending on which algorithm they pick. I've never seen someone use Sort to determine UI-behavior before, novel, but unusual.

If you do want to use a sort algorithm maybe go for insertion sort (compare each new item against existing list using binary search to find where it goes) or quicksort (partition the elements into two sets by comparing one against all others).

But ... I don't think either of these is going to be a great user experience, both will feel repetitive. And, given that this is a subjective question, the answer often isn't a purely linear ordering of items. People aren't consistent and they will create cycles A->B->C->A when they do this.

So here's a suggestion for a UI experience that feels less repetitive, can handle subjective anomalies and is easy to implement:

Pick pairs of images maybe at random and ask the user to rank one over the other. Let the user be inconsistent if they wish. Take each pair A->B that they create and put them in a Graph. Find any nodes in the graph that aren't connected yet, or which only have a single connection, and focus asking how they rank against nodes you've already scored.

That way if they've ranked A->B->C and then rank C->D the algorithm isn't going to keep asking how A and B compare to D.

And finally apply a technique called `Topological Sort` and ignore any cycles you find. An approximate topological sort if you like.

There's a Graph library (that I wrote) which includes this capability. See [this test](https://github.com/IanMercer/AboditGraph/blob/main/Abodit.Graph.Tests/GraphTests.cs#L116) for an example of calling `.TopologicalSortApprox()`.

Once all the items are in the graph you can keep going, using comparisons that try to flatten the graph closer to a straight line. But at any time if the user gets bored and wants to stop (nobody wants to do n log n comparisons!) you at least have an approximate rank you can use.

Comment: So what you are saying is the sort function compares them so often because it's comparing it for situations that aren't relevant for what I'm doing? If I understand you correctly. What I'm getting is to make graphs A->B->C and D->E->F. If C and F are the best of the groups then compare if C > or <  and connect C to F or F to C then sort it to get (if F is > C) F, C, E, B, D, A from best to worst?

Comment: @DoshorteDovencio I updated the answer to try to clarify and added another point about the hazards of using a built-in sort function to drive your UI.